# Mapbox popups at wrong location when map is at max zoom (multiple world copies visible)

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have an issue with a Mapbox map where Popups attached to a Marker are displayed the wrong position, when the map is zoomed out, so we see multiple world copies. See sample below. The Popup are displayed at the correct position when the map is zoomed in and only one world is visible.

[image]

This is a simplified version of the code used to add Markers + Popups and display them:

```
 // Add markers to the map
features.forEach(function (marker: any, i: number) {

const popUpContent = '<div>Sample</div>'

// Create the popup
const popup = new mapboxgl.Popup({ offset: 25 })
  .setHTML(popUpContent)
  .on('open', function (event: any) {
    const activePoi = document.getElementsByClassName(poiId)[0]
    activePoi.classList.add('active')
  })
  .on('close', function () {
    const activePoi = document.getElementsByClassName(poiId)[0]
    if (activePoi) {
      activePoi.classList.remove('active')
    }
  })

let mark = new mapboxgl.Marker(markerElement)
  .setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)
  .setPopup(popup)
  .addTo(map)
})
```

#### Question

How can I solve this issue, so that popup appears correctly above their respective Marker, even when multiple world copies are visible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mapbox's solution to this: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/popup-on-click/

```js
// When a click event occurs on a feature in the places layer, open a popup at the
// location of the feature, with description HTML from its properties.
map.on('click', 'places', function(e) {

    var coordinates = e.features[0].geometry.coordinates.slice();
    var description = e.features[0].properties.description;

    // Ensure that if the map is zoomed out such that multiple
    // copies of the feature are visible, the popup appears
    // over the copy being pointed to.
    while (Math.abs(e.lngLat.lng - coordinates[0]) > 180) {
    coordinates[0] += e.lngLat.lng > coordinates[0] ? 360 : -360;
    }

    new mapboxgl.Popup()
    .setLngLat(coordinates)
    .setHTML(description)
    .addTo(map);
    });

    // ...

}
```

Comment: I have seen that example code, but I don't add points using the `map.addSource()` [1] API, which the sample code uses. I attach Popups to a specific Marker. So this is not that relevant. I'm interested in a solution related to the code I posted above.

[1] https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/map/#map#addsource